# Rails 5 File POST file as body in Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest

I have a small image file in my text/fixtures/filesfolder that I am trying to call an external API with. It is a JPG. I am trying to test it with this method in my controller test

```
 test 'post image to external API' do
    binding.pry
    image = fixture_file_upload('files/simple_image.jpg', 'image/jpg')
    post '/api/services/image_processor', params: {body: image}
    assert_response :success
  end
```

Unfortunately, if I do this the result is Invalid request parameters: invalid %-encoding, which makes sense because I'm posting a param and not a body.

How do I set my uploaded file to be the body of the request? I can post the file body with postman and it works excellently, but I'd like automate the process for testing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used this:

```
image = fixture_file_upload('files/simple_file.jpg', 'image/jpg', :binary)
post '/api/services/image_processor', params: image.tempfile, headers: { 'CONTENT-TYPE': 'image/jpg' }
assert_response :success
```

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do it is use following code in your controller

a) If you pass file to a method that expects a path (like CSV parser)

`params[:file].path`

b) or this if you need file contents

`params[:file].read`

And then in your test

```
file = fixture_file_upload('path/to/some/file.csv')
post '/api/endpoint',
     params: { file: file },
     headers: { 'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' }
```

This way in `params` you will find a properly working file upload

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007ff3f1ea8e80 @tempfile= ...
```

Comment: It's a binary image file, not a csv

Comment: Which for rails file upload doesn't matter one bit. The problem with your code is `.tempfile` which does not work in Rails 5 and I'm pretty sure didn't work in previous versions either.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question... This is still posting the file as params. What happens if I want to, for instance, `PUT` the file to the active storage disk controller URL? I need the file as the body of the request, not in a specific parameter. With curl it would be `curl -X PUT "my_url" --upload-file ~/my/file/location`, how do I do that with put() or post()

Comment: @nzifnab could you please explain how are params vs files different in `multipart/form-data`? I'm happy to provide the RFC link for your convenience https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578